# FitNesse Suites Variables

Tags: fitnesse

I'm working with FitNesse and the first time trying with Suite.
I had my test scripts in many parts as I was receiving Jave Heap errors.

Now I'd thought try using suites.

I have a Fitnesse module that load many variables. This module was included in each Part of the suite so I tried to use this variable module just at the beginning of the suite using the `!see` function.

Unfortunatly the variables aren't stored and used for the pages in the suite.

How can I pass down the variables?
eg. the variables from VariablesSetUp do not pass down to the other pages.

```
!see .FitNesse.VariablesSetUp
!see .FitNesse.TestDate1
!see .FitNesse.TestDate2
!see .FitNesse.TestDate3
```

This is a bit tricky to explain; let me know if I haven't made myself clear.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

I think you want to use the [`!include` markup](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.MarkupPageInclude).  Using `!include -c PagePath` will insert the given page (`!define` values and all) into the current one.